# How can I put a slider inside item 1?

Tags: html, css, grid

How can I put a slider inside item 1?
I categorized the page using the grid method. But I don't know how to act inside each part according to its size.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-gap: 1em;

}

.item {
    text-align: center;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

#item-1{
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 1 / 5;
}

#item-5 {
    grid-row: 2/6;
    grid-column: 7/8;
}

#item-8 {
    grid-row:3/6;
    grid-column: 1/7 ;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="item-1">item 1</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-5">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-6">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-7">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-8">Item 8</div>
</div>
```

I categorized the page using the grid method. But I don't know how to act inside each part according to its size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but once you are inside one of these items you don't have to "act" any particular special way.  You can do whatever you want.  It will have the default box-model layout unless you specify something else, like a flexbox layout like I have below that will vertically center the content

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-gap: 1em;

}

.item {
    text-align: center;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

#item-1{
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 1 / 5;
    

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#item-5 {
    grid-row: 2/6;
    grid-column: 7/8;
}

#item-8 {
    grid-row:3/6;
    grid-column: 1/7 ;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="item-1">
    <p>here is some content</p>
    <input type='range'/>
    <p>here is some more content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-5">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-6">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-7">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-8">Item 8</div>
</div>
```